# Admob iOS 24.3 Apps in Kids category must get parental permission

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, admob, app-store-connect

**Current live app :** I have app named "App for Kiddo". App contains in-app purchases and **iAd**. I have successfully implemented Parental Control on in-app purchases and app is currently approved by Apple and available in iTunes to download.

**New Version Rejected in iTunes** : Removed **iAd** and added **Admob**. App is currently rejected with below explanation from Apple. I have method for parental control ready but not sure how to use it with

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
[request tagForChildDirectedTreatment:YES];
/// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewDidReceiveAd");
}

/// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)adView
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
  NSLog(@"adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

/// Tells the delegate that a full screen view will be presented in response
/// to the user clicking on an ad.
- (void)adViewWillPresentScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewWillPresentScreen");
}

/// Tells the delegate that the full screen view will be dismissed.
- (void)adViewWillDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewWillDismissScreen");
}

/// Tells the delegate that the full screen view has been dismissed.
- (void)adViewDidDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewDidDismissScreen");
}

**/// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
/// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
- (void)adViewWillLeaveApplication:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewWillLeaveApplication");
}**
```

With my understanding I can write code in adViewWillLeaveApplication for parental control but not sure what to write

```
if(parental control){
//Success show advertisement???? What to write?
}else {
//Don't show advertisement?????? What to write?
}
```

**From Apple**
24.3 - Apps in the Kids Category must get parental permission or use a parental gate before allowing the user to link out of the app or engage in commerce
24.3 Details

You have selected the Kids Category for your app, but it includes links out of the app or engages in commerce without first obtaining parental permission. Specifically, your app includes advertisements that, when tapped, takes the user to a web page.

Please update your app to incorporate a parental gate before the user can leave the app and ensure that the parental gate cannot be disabled.

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Comment: @ram i found lot of links but not reliable. I'm going to write to google. I'll update this once hear from them

Comment: @AmodGokhale Did you found any solution on this. Me too facing some issue related to this. My app has been rejected and I have stated the issue here ->( 1.3 - Safety - Kids Category.

You have selected the Kids category for your app, but it includes links out of the app or engages in commerce without first obtaining parental permission. Specifically, your app includes certain advertisements that, when tapped, take the user to a web page or the App Store.) Let me know if we have any solution.

Comment: Actually we added a parental control at initial ad launch but they suggested us to add a parental lock on every ad. Is there any way to fix this issue without adding parental control everytime?

Comment: @Madhavan - with my knowledge its not possible with admob. Try checking other ad service provider.

Comment: @Madhavan - .3 - Safety - Kids Category. You have selected the Kids category for your app, but it includes links out of the app or engages in commerce without first obtaining parental permission. - > This we fixed by adding a random math puzzle popup. Increased its complexity such that only adult can solve the puzzle and then allow him/her to move out of app